# How to group by using reduce in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects, which I want to group by meter:

```
[
    {
        _id: { year:2022, meter:12 },
        x:1,
        y:0
    },
    ...
]
```

The problem is I am unable to use the `reduce` function to do so. I tried other methods too, like using `group`:

```
const result = inventory.group(({ _id.meter }) => _id.meter);
```

The problem is that none of the methods accept a key inside a key (i.e `_id` will work but `_id.meter` won't)

```
const products = [
  { name: 'apples', category: 'fruits' },
  { name: 'oranges', category: 'fruits' },
  { name: 'potatoes', category: 'vegetables' }
];

const groupByCategory = products.reduce((group, product) => {
  const { category } = product;
  group[category] = group[category] ?? [];
  group[category].push(product);
  return group;
}, {});
```

Another example I found above which again doesn't work if I write `category.meter` or something like that.

Can someone help me how to modify the code so I am able to group it by "a key inside a key"?

Comment: When you say "group by meter" -- what do you mean, exactly? Should elements be grouped by integer value of meter, i.e. one group for elements with meter value of 12, another with meter value of 13, and so on?

Comment: In any case `({ _id.meter }) => _id.meter` is not valid JavaScript -- if you want to bind `meter` to the corresponding property on an object referenced by the `_id` property on what is passed to the function, the syntax is `({ _id: { meter } }) => meter`.

Comment: Should elements be grouped by integer value of meter, i.e. one group for elements with meter value of 12, another with meter value of 13, and so on?
Yes